# editable field even if the Edit button is not clicked

Tags: widget, odoo

I hope everyone is fine.
I have an issue regarding the widget "priority", I have a selection field "rating" that has this widget.

```
<field name="rating" widget="priority" />
```

the problem is this widget is editable either I click on Edit or not.
any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use this class > class="oe_edit_only"

Like this

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  I added this class and I had this behavior:
in the edit mode i can edit it, but when I save, the field becomes invisible (the stars disappear)